# How to remove scratches from LG mobile camera lens (with coating)?

Tags: lens, cleaning, cameraphones, smartphone, lens-coatings

I recently bought a used LG G2 (T-mobile) from market and later on noticed that it does not takes the photos with expected quality.

> Sample Photos (I see a visible difference when I see through another
>   LG G2 - placed right next to my LG G2)
>
> http://workupload.com/file/zd1mTi7s
>
> http://workupload.com/file/ZxXvQmMB

I feel that the issue could be possibly because of scratches on Camera lens (or its coating). I searched on internet and found that we can resolve the scratch issues by using toothpaste (with toothbrush?) or some polish.

I am just not sure if it is the right solution for my scenario.

- Should I simply remove the coating as the scratches are supposed to be coating only? Is this approach good and what possible issues could i face for removing coating (Knowing that I might not able to find replacement coating for my mobile model)

OR

- Should I try to remove scratch from the coating only (if possible)

[image]

Comment: Required reading: [LensRentals on scratches](http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches). Or in other words, the scratches probably aren't the problem - please post some sample photos.

Comment: I have added few sample photos taken through my LG G2. To be honest, I didnot felt any issue until I placed my LG-G2 with my friends LG-G2. View through his mobile was more crystal and that is why I concluded that it could be because of dust/scratches!

Comment: Sample photos need to be of the same scene under the same conditions for them to be valid. Two totally different photos of two totally different scenes tells us nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your photo it looks like someone added a plastic protection cover over the lens. Whether it was supposed to be temporary or permanent, I would just remove it, as it now yellowed and cracked. Just peel it off and you should see a big improvement.

[image]

Comment: That might even be a bit of plastic shipped over the lens from the factory initially. That's _supposed_ to be removed.

Comment: The dark spot looks to me like it is where the original coating intended to be permanent has already been removed.